# css3 transform perspective for a div element on window onload

Tags: jquery, css

hi all am trying css3 perspective it came while window is loading

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vivekranth/CNg3t/13/)

```
._red{
    background-color:#f00;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 45deg );
    }
```

i need to rotate the div element using css3 perceptive while on loading  window or click any 
trigger using jquery.how to do it and how i do full rotate there.

Comment: Just apply the class on load?

Comment: Not that this will work only in ie10. No earlier version of ie. and you will have to add -webkit & -moz prefix's for this to work in Mozilla & Chrome

Comment: Check this link for a good demo http://kevchapman.co.uk/css/webkit-css-perspective-demo/

Answer (score 1):

JQuery Method:

```
// this will handle on load and the click event

$(function(){
   $el = $('._red');
    // apply the foo class on load
    $el.addClass('foo'); 
    // toggle a class on click
    $el.on('click', function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('bar');
    });
});
```

Or, you could use keyframes... This won't work for the click event though, unless you want to add a `:target` element.

```
._red{
    background-color:#f00;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 45deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY(45deg); 
    -webkit-animation: rotate 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); }
}
```

**[Keyframes Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CNg3t/18/)**

Keep in mind, you'll have to add whichever vendor prefixes you are supporting.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i altered your jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CNg3t/16/

```
#me {
    -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
```